# Remove certain characters if they are not in a specific location in a string #python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out the following function situation from my python class.  I've gotten the code to remove the three letters but from exactly where they don't want me to. IE removing WGU from the first line where it's supposed to stay but not from WGUJohn.

```
# Complete the function to remove the word WGU from the given string
# ONLY if it's not the first word and return the new string
def removeWGU(mystring):
    #if mystring[0]!= ('WGU'):
        #return mystring.strip('WGU')
    #if mystring([0]!= 'WGU')
        #return mystring.split('WGU')
    
# Student code goes here
    
# expected output: WGU Rocks
print(removeWGU('WGU Rocks'))
    
# expected output: Hello, John
print(removeWGU('Hello, WGUJohn'))
```

Comment: Getting stack overflow to answer your homework question isn't a great way to learn Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def removeWGU(mystring):
    return mystring[0] + mystring[1:].replace("WGU","")
```

Other responses I seen wouldn't work on a edgy case where there is multiple "WGU" in the text and one at the beginning, such as

```py
print(removeWGU("WGU, something else, another WGU..."))
```

Comment: You need to split mystring first

Comment: @7koFnMiP to do what? Currently the slice is just here to forbid the replace function to trigger on the 3 first character.

Comment: ````mystring[0]```` refers to ````W```` in this case not ````WGU````, is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, by removing the first character from the replace() function, the replacing can trigger for any 'WGU' in the text except if it is at the very beginning of the full string because the 'W' would then be missing. For example 'aWGUbcdef' would also change to 'abcdef'

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```
def removeWGU(mystring):
    s = mystring.split()
    if s[0] == "WGU":
        return mystring
    else:
        return mystring.replace("WGU","")
print(removeWGU('WGU Rocks'))
print(removeWGU('Hello, WGUJohn'))
```